# Using Math text in the website

Tags: support

I want to express a few equations centered around a transistor circuit, however when the circuit gets a little complicated and involves a regenerative feedback, the equations are not discernible anymore in plain text. I want to know how to use mathematical text in the stack exchange electrical engineering site. I couldn't ask this question there because the owners are extremely uptight about anything off topic, I guess even this is off topic. Kindly help

Comment: Is the following [Latex sanbox](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/434/test-the-new-latex-markdown-in-this-sandbox-question) helpful? You can have a play around with how it works there and also examine some of the existing samples posted.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help. Will play around with it and let you knw if I have any doubts...:)